# C# Directing Data Based on ComboBox Selection

Tags: c#, if-statement, datagridview, combobox

In my program, I want to put user-entered data into a category, based on what they selected in the COMBOBOX.

There are four categories, and four DATAGRIDVIEWS that are within a TABCONTROL (on a separate form).

I'm able to add the information a user entered, but the COMBOBOX doesn't have it's functionality yet.

How do I make it so that if the user selects "category 1", it sends the data they entered into dataGridView1, "category 2" to dataGridView2?

I know this will require "if, else-if" statement, but I'm not sure as to how to direct the data based on the COMBOBOX selection to the appropriate DGV.

Comment: use combo ``SelectedIndexChanged`` event

Comment: [C# ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the ComboBox a required field on the entry form. When the user submits the entry, it should be routed to the proper category. Use the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` (or `.SelectedText` or `.SelectedValue`) to determine which category was selected. The `ComboBox.DropDownStyle` should probably be `DropDownList` so the user has to select from the listed options.

If the categorization happens after the entry, then you should have an `Apply` or `Categorize` button that performs the actual categorization. The logic is pretty simple:

```
private void CategorizeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (CategoryComboBox.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0: // Category 1
            // Code to send to Category 1
            break;
        case 1: // Category 2, repeat as necessary
            // Code to send to Category 2
            break;   
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a category!");
            CategoryComboBox.Focus();
            return;
    }
}
```

This can be refactored and simplified if the code to send to the categories is almost identical. Then you can use the SelectedIndex to identify the target DataGridView instead and reduce the code length and repitition.

Comment: There isn't a categorization button, but rather, I'm taking whatever the user entered to determine where the data will go.

Also, when I attempt to use the code you provided, it says that CategoryComboBox does not exist in the current context. This is my first week of programming:), so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I interpreted the "where the data will go" to be the category. So I named the combobox `CategoryComboBox` and that is just the name you assign to the combobox. If there is a better name, then just change the name. I see in your code sample, you left the default name `combobox1` but you are free to rename as appropriate, and I would highly encourage you to use meaningful names. You should also look into naming conventions if you aren't familiar with them.

Comment: Using your example of the switch statement, how do I get it to work; I get the following error message: The name 'combobox1' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a better or valid way to do it:

```
if(combobox1.SelectedValue = "category1"){
     //user-entered info goes to DGV1

else if(combobox1.SelectedValue = "category2")
     //user-entered info goes to DGV2

     //.etc.
```

Comment: This is not necessarily better, just different. If this is clearer to you, then use it. There are some advantages to `switch` but nothing significant in this scenario.